# How to log login and logout on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, login, logs

I would like to know when I logged in and out on my mac.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Open up a terminal and enter the command: last

```
chris@chriss-mbp-2:~/Documents/dev/git/$ last

    chris     ttys005                   Sun Dec 22 01:51 - 02:57  (01:06)
    chris     ttys005                   Sun Dec 22 01:50 - 01:51  (00:00)
    chris     ttys004                   Sat Dec 21 13:32 - 19:53 (1+06:20)
    chris     ttys003                   Sat Dec 21 13:32   still logged in
    chris     ttys002                   Sat Dec 21 13:32   still logged in
    chris     ttys001                   Sat Dec 21 13:32   still logged in
    chris     ttys000                   Sat Dec 21 13:32   still logged in
    chris     console                   Sat Dec 21 13:32   still logged in
    reboot    ~                         Sat Dec 21 13:32 
    shutdown  ~                         Sat Dec 21 13:32
```

Further details about last can be found in the man pages [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/last.1.html).

Comment: It does not work as I expect. I'm log until ca. 15min and I get this only one line for today: charles   ttys000                   Tue Dec 24 11:27   still logged in. The date command prints "Tue Dec 24 11:27:02 CET 2013".

Comment: @charles could you please explain what you are exactly trying to accomplish? It's not quite clear from your question as it's very brief.

Comment: I want to track how long I worked every day. e.g. [08:05] Login, [12:20] Logout (launch) [13:35] Login, [19:05] Logout (back at home).

Comment: Actually I would like to also track locked screen.